# flutter can't go to project files, can't find main.dart

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I am very new to flutter, and I created a new demo project which directly directed me to `main.dart` in the editor. I had the folders specified as in  [this link.](https://medium.com/@queen_shecoder/understanding-the-files-and-folders-generated-by-a-new-flutter-project-d9dcfd639a09)

The folder goes as follows,

```
Dart_tool
.idea
Android
IOS
Lib
Linux,Macos,Web
Tests
.gitignore
.metadata
etc etc etc...
```

I remember `main.dart` was in `Lib`

Yet I clicked on the dropdown and chose one of these, then I look at each one of them and Cannot find the `Lib` Folder. Where can I go back to viewing that folder structure. Excuses I am very new to flutter.

[Directory Dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AvmyQ.png)

It always goes as `StudioProjecs/untitled/...`

Where is the `Lib` folder in here ?

EDIT:

If I go to `Project`, I still can't find the `main.dart` file. If I go click `Run app`, the app runs perfectly with the demo page.

Here is the project's directory.

[Project directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7A77K.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modified to project instead of Android [image]